# Как включить строку в текстовый файл под vxWorks командами C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, vxworks

Здравствуйте!

При создании текстового файла (стартового скрипта) под OS vxWorks необходимо включить следующую строку:

```
ldz "/tffs/apps.Z.out"
```

Включаю `<stdio.h>`, открываю файл `(fp = fopen)`, пишу:

```
fputs("ldz "/tffs/apps.Z.out"\n", fp);
```

Получаю сообщение:

> undefined symbol 'tffs'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как включить этот символ/слово или, возможно, надо правильно расставить кавычки/слэши/скобки?

P.S. Уточнил: tffs без предшествующего слэша воспринимает нормально, на заключительные кавычки перед `\n"` ругается - syntax error. Текст должен быть записан в строку именно так:

```
ldz "/tffs/apps.Z.out"
```

Comment: Cool, огромное спасибо за помощь. Получилось создать файл-загрузочный скрипт с необходимыми параметрами запуска прямо в файловой системе роутера. Итоговую задачу решить, правда, не удалось - apps.Z.out при загрузке не принимает параметры скрипта( буду разбираться) и переписывает его по-своему (сохраняя filename (!). Надо менять этот бинарник или модифицировать его, но это другая история.

Comment: @Cool Поторопился.  Параметры скрипта написанного благодаря Cool сохраняются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что строка содержит вложенные кавычки, то есть

```
"ldz "/tffs/apps.Z.out"\n"
```

воспринимается как две строки и не строка, что и вызывает ошибку

```
"ldz ", /tffs/apps.Z.out, "\n"
```

Нужно добавить обратный слэш перед вложенными кавычками (вместо `"` сделать `\"`), тогда строка будет восприниматься как единое целое

```
"ldz \"/tffs/apps.Z.out\"\n"
```